# Dynamic Menu sourced from DB in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am newish to Rails and wanted to get some help creating a dynamic menu for a blog site I am coding.  So the idea of it is that I can create a new blog with posts and not have to re-code the menu bar, but instead have the menu look at the DB and show all the blogs it has.  I would of thought this is fairly simple and maybe I am using the wrong wording or looking for the wrong things.  Oh I should say that I am still using rails 3.2.13.

Currently I have the following code:

blogs_controller.rb:

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
# GET /blogs
# GET /blogs.json
def index
@blogs = Blog.all

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @blogs }
 end
end
--other code--
```

Then in my views\blogs\index.html.erb:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Created Date</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= blog.title %></td>
    <td><%= blog.created_at.localtime.strftime('%d %b %y %H:%M' ) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', blog %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_blog_path(blog) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', blog, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

and all this works well to display the index of my blogs, but I was hoping there was a way to have the following in my view\layouts\ _header.html.erb:

```
<header>
  <ul class="menu center">
    <li><%= link_to root_path do %> Home <% end %></li>
    <li><%= link_to contact_path do %> Contact Me <% end %></li>
    <li><%= link_to blogs_path do %> Blogs <% end %>
    <ul>
    # hoping I could add below???
    <% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
        <li><%= blog.title %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
 </ul>
</header>
```

Any help or hints would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibility 1:

You could add a before_filter in your application_controller.rb which sets the @blogs variable for your header menu.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :set_blogs_for_menu

  private

  def set_blogs_for_menu
    @blogs = Blog.all
  end

end
```

Now @blogs is always available in all views.

Possibility 2:

You can create a helper in your app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def create_blog_menu
    blogs = (defined? @blogs) ? @blogs : Blog.all

    menu = ""
    blogs.each do |blog|
      menu += "<li>#{blog.title}</li>"
    end
    raw menu
  end

end
```

app/view\layouts\ _header.html.erb:

```
<header>
  <ul class="menu center">
    <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Blog", blogs_path %>
      <ul>
        <%= create_blog_menu %>
      </ul>
    </li>
  <ul>
</header>
```

I would prefer possibility 1, but I want to show you more ways to realize that.

Comment: Thanks heaps, I think I tried possibility 1, but didn't put in the private and tried doing something silly, thanks Matthias